# Postgres- comparing two arrays in the where clause optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I am comparing an array inside my table with an array that has the maching IDs. this query performs slowly as soon as the number of items in the passed in array gets larger. I was wondering if there are any further optimizations that I can do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DataOrdering"."GetHierarchyProductsCount"(
    categoryhierarchyids integer[])
    RETURNS TABLE("TotalCount" integer) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT Count(*)::int as TotalCount FROM "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping" PDM
        WHERE PDM."CategoryHierarchyIds" && categoryhierarchyids;       
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION "DataOrdering"."GetHierarchyProductsCount"(integer[])
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

table shcema:

```
CREATE TABLE "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping"
(
    "ProductDesc" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ProductCode" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ProductDescMappingId" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping_ProductDescMappingId_seq"'::regclass),
    "CategoryHierarchyIds" integer[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::integer[],
    CONSTRAINT pk_productdescmappingid PRIMARY KEY ("ProductDescMappingId"),
    CONSTRAINT uc_productdescmapping UNIQUE ("ProductCode")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping"
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: ix_productcategoryhierarchy

-- DROP INDEX "DataOrdering".ix_productcategoryhierarchy;

CREATE INDEX ix_productcategoryhierarchy
    ON "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping" USING btree
    ("CategoryHierarchyIds" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: ix_productdescmapping

-- DROP INDEX "DataOrdering".ix_productdescmapping;

CREATE INDEX ix_productdescmapping
    ON "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping" USING btree
    ("ProductCode" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: Why is the function declared to return a table of integers?

Comment: @Lennart the calling code only is able to handle tables and not single values, so this is why it has been written like this.

Comment: Is it still slow if you run the select query in the function body? I.e. `SELECT Count(*)::int as TotalCount FROM "DataOrdering"."ProductDescMapping" PDM
        WHERE PDM."CategoryHierarchyIds" && yourArray`

Comment: for a passed in array with 5275 ids and a table containing 427678 rows it is able to complete in 1 secs 324 msec, is this what you would expect? can this be further optimized?

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the system, but it does not sound catastrophic. Is there a difference when you run it through your function?

Comment: @Lennart interestingly running it through the function takes double the time! changing it to return a single value rather than a table, makes the execution times match.

Comment: What happen if you change rows 1000 to 1?